# In Gulp how to prevent gulp-sass to minify css into 1 file

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass, node-sass

Is there a way to tell `gulp-sass` to process SASS files but still keep the source folder structure. We don't want them to be minified/concatenated into one main file. For example if I have:

```
src/
  components/
    _header.scss
    _sidebar.scss
    _card.scss
```

Can I tell it to process them into:

```
dist/
  components/
    header.css
    sidebar.css
    card.css
```

#### Gulpfile

```
gulp.task('styles:dist', () => {
  return gulp
    .src('./src/styles/**/*.+(scss|sass|css)', { base: './' })
    .pipe(
      sass({
        outputStyle: 'expanded',
      }).on('error', sass.logError)
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide your gulpfile as well ?

Comment: Thanks for responding @Amaury Hanser! I've added the gulpfile.

Comment: How are your files named ? ``header.scss`` or ``_header.scss`` ? Because it shouldn't concatenate them

Comment: sorry they're named as `_header.scss`. I've updated the question.

Comment: `_header.scss` with the `_` means that it's something to be imported in another sass file. If you name your file without the `_` it will compile both files.

Comment: Search for "partials" and sass.  When you use the leading underscore, you create a partial which will not be separately compiled into a css file.

Answer (score 0):

First install cleanCSS gulp plugin then run your task for convert scss or sass or less files to css then use css task for convert all css files to one minified and merge css file.

```
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');

gulp.task('css', () => {
return gulp.src('./src/styles/**/*.css')
  .pipe(cleanCSS({
      compatibility: 'ie8',
      level: {
          1: {
              specialComments: 0,
          },
      },
  }))
  .pipe('./dist'))
});
```